$builder->get()->getResultObject() in codeigniter4 is returning an array instead a object
I´m trying to do a join in other tables with builder in codeigniter 4.
When I use:
$model->find(id) they return an object with the fields, so in view i can direct print with $return->fieldname;
but when I use $builder, I get an array with 0 index and an object inside this array.
I want a return like i get from the $model->find();
code:
model:
    public function efindOne($id)
{
    $builder = $this->db->table('equipe');
    $builder->select('*');
    $builder->where('equipe.idEf =', $id);
    $builder->join('fornecedores', 'fornecedores.idFo = equipe.idFo');
    $builder->join('areas', 'areas.idAr = equipe.idAr');
    $builder->join('edicao', 'equipe.idEf = edicao.idEf');
    //$builder->limit(1);
    return $builder->get()->getResultObject();
}

controller:
      $equipe= $modelEquipe->efindOne($verId);

result:

When I do:
  $equipe= $modelEquipe->find($verId);

i get:

as expected...
I already try to limit the result, try to convert array to object, I can´t understand what I'm doing wrong

You get a collection which is an array containing objects. Use $equipe = $modelEquipe->findOne($verId)[0]; to get the first object of that array.

getResultObject() is the equivalent of findAll(). Use getRowObject() if you want only one object returned.

You can check below for single row. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#getrow

The solution $equipe = $modelEquipe->findOne($verId)[0];  work!!!! I don't know that I can do that!!
